# Shiv executable missing virtualenv in the PATH to work

Tags: python-3.x

I am building an executable using shiv with the following Makefile

```
benv:
    python3.11 -m venv bvenv
    . bvenv/bin/activate; pip install myapplication/
    . bvenv/bin/activate; pip install shiv

build: benv
    . bvenv/bin/activate; shiv --site-packages bvenv --compressed -p '/usr/bin/env python3.11' -o mycompiled-app -e app.main.py
```

However, if I try to run it (on different machines) it always returns

```
/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 76, in import_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 76, in import_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 253, in bootstrap
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 81, in import_string
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 81, in import_string
  File "/opt/myappdirectory-app/mycompiled-app/_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 59, in import_string
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

However, I realized that if I set the PATH variable, the app can run.
Why?

`PATH=/home/myuser/myapp/bvenv/bin ./mycompiled-app run`

I unzipped the shiv file and checked that indeed there is the `app` module and the main.py file inside.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The right command is

`. bvenv/bin/activate; shiv --site-packages bvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ --compressed -p '/usr/bin/env python3.11' -o mycompiled-app -e app.main.py`